# Fourier tranform of decaying periodic function $f(t+k)=e^{-k^2/2}e^{-kt}f(t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

I have a function which I know is almost periodic, except that it is decaying

$$f(t+k)=e^{-k^2/2}e^{-kt}f(t)=e^{-k(k/2+t)}f(t)$$

for integers $k\in\mathbb Z$. For example if I choose $k=1$ I get

$$f(t+1)=e^{-1/2}e^{-t}f(t)$$
or if I choose $k=-1$ I get

$$f(t-1)=e^{-1/2}e^{t}f(t)=e^{-k(k/2+t)}f(t)$$

This means that if we choose some point $t_0=0$ we could define $f_0=f(t_0=0)$ and write

$$f(t=k)=e^{-k^2/2}f_0$$

I would like to know whether it is possible to use this to extract information about the Fourier transform of $f$. I suspect that using this information it will be possible to identify the Fourier transform, at least in some region.

If this is not possible in general, then what information can we identify about $\hat f(x)$?

I have tried taking the Fourier transform of both sides of the initial expression but I don't know how to evaluate the Fourier transform of the right hand side (which reduces to something like a Laplace transformation)

$$e^{-k^2/2}\int f(t) e^{-kt}e^{ixt}\text{d} t=e^{-k^2/2}\int f(t) e^{(ix-k)t}\text{d} t$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you define $g(t) = e^{t^2/2} f(t)$, you find
$$
g(t+k) = e^{k^2/2+tk+t^2/2} f(t+k) = e^{t^2/2} f(t) = g(t)
$$
hence you condition is equivalent to say that $e^{t^2/2} f(t)$ is a $1$-periodic function. Equivalently, it means you can write $f(t) = g(t)\,e^{-t^2/2}$ for some $1$-periodic function $g$. Taking the Fourier transform yields
$$
\widehat{f}(x) = \widehat{g} * \widehat{e^{-t^2/2}} = \widehat{g} * e^{-2(\pi x)^2}
$$
But since $g$ is periodic, its Fourier transform is related to its Fourier series since
$$
\widehat{g}(x) = \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} c_k(g) \,\widehat{e^{2i\pi k x}} = \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} c_k(g) \,\delta_k
$$
where $\delta_k$ is the Dirac delta distribution centered at $x=k$ and the $c_k(g)$ are the Fourier coefficients of $g$. Now doing the convolution gives
$$
\widehat{f}(x) = \int\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} c_k(g)\, e^{-2(\pi (x-y))^2} \,\delta_k(\mathrm d y) = \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} c_k(g)\, e^{-2(\pi (x-k))^2}.
$$
You cannot really simplify it further since $g$ can be any $1$-periodic function in general.

Comment: This is great! Do you have a reference for an analysis like this? Or one in which the terminology of such functions are defined? PS: You might have noticed that this was what I wanted to ask in my previous question, but I simplified it too much so that it was meaningless!

Comment: And c_k are the Fourier coefficients, meaning that they are each constant for some function g, i.e. they depend on the whole function g, but for a given g they are not dependent on the position in $\hat f(x)$?

Comment: No, no specific reference. Are some results I use unknown to you ? Yes, the Fourier coefficients are numbers. Defined as $\int e^{-2i\pi ky} g(y)\,\mathrm d y$

Comment: No, I am familiar with each step but I wouldn't have thought to define the helper function g

Comment: If I know that $\hat f(x)$ has a similar relation, e.g. something like $\hat f(x+m)=e^{-m(m/2+x)}\hat f(x)$, would this provide enough information to calculate $\hat f(x)$?

Comment: I posted a follow up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417753/relationship-between-function-and-its-fourier-transform-multiplied-by-another-fu